# vscode-debugger hangs on the "using Revise" statement

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, vscode-debugger

When I use Visual Studio code to debug a Julia file, it hangs on the "using Revise" statement.  No debugging button seems to do anything, except the stop button.  Does anyone know of a solution?

```
using Revise

println("Hello")
```

[image: vscode screenshot]

Comment: Works for me. What Revise version do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.  In vs-code there is a bright blue bar at the bottom.  Clicking Julia env: and changing it from v1.5 to JulaiPro_v1.5.2-1 fixed everything.

It has something to do with:

```
julia> Base.load_path()
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "C:\\Users\\<user>\\.julia\\environments\\JuliaPro_v1.5.2-1\\Project.toml"
 "C:\\Users\\<user>\\.julia\\environments\\v1.5\\Project.toml"
 "C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.5.2-1\\Julia-1.5.2\\share\\julia\\stdlib\\v1.5"
```

The v1.5 path didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when I get behavior like this, the first step is always to restart my IDE, quit Julia, and re-try. Just tested this and it works for me, can you perhaps open an issue here: https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl if this is still an issue or provide steps to reproduce.